# Using Android Apps on Ubuntu Mobile OS

Tags: ubuntu-touch, android, nexus-4

An OS is not typically I look for in a mobile or a laptop. Since almost a year now, I have been addicted to this game Clash of Clans on my Nexus 4 running Android 5.1. I am looking for experimenting with my Nexus and run Ubuntu Touch on it. Is there any possible way we can run Android apps on Ubuntu touch or Ubuntu mobile OS?

Answer (score 0):

No, its not possible, and I never heard of plans to include this feature.

I'm sorry.